# Adding regex to detect a word that repeats 3 characters?

Tags: php, regex

I have searched and searched but I cannot find anything quite exactly like what I need. I have a code:

```
$repeater = "pompom";

    if (preg_match('/([a-zA-Z])\1{3}/', $repeater)) {
    echo "Yes, $repeater does repeat 3 characters.<br>";
}
else {
    echo "No, $repeater does not repeat 3 characters.<br>";
}
```

(I can barely understand regex as it is... so just ignore my current regex.. it's just a mixture of randomness I began to type.)
Anyhow, I need the regex code to return
**true** for words like
**pompom**
**grugru**
**mopmop**
**cancan**
etc...

and return **false** for words like
**coocoo**
**daadaa**
**allall**
**giigii**
etc.

The regex must detect and return true for any word that has **3 different characters** that **repeat more than once in that word**.
This must work for words that have characters that are not necessarily in sequence with one another. I have found solutions to that. Words such as "cooo" or "pooool" is not what I need to apply this regex for. Note: This must return **True** only for words that have 3 or more different letters in the word **and** are repeated more than once. Such as, pompom..
This should return false for words like coocoo because there are only 2 different letters in the word.

Again, please ignore my current regex it was just what I had when I decided to ask for some help. I've tried probably 200 different methods, all wrong of course :].
Any help would be nice, maybe we can figure this out together I just need some ideas to bounce off of.

Comment: To help you understand regex:  https://regexone.com/

Comment: I will check that out now @nfn niel, thanks

Comment: I also answered the question, too.  That's just my favorite site.

Comment: For making this an even nicer question (I agree, it is already interesting), could you give more diverse sample input, to match and not to match? I would be interested in "moppom" and "moppopomm". And could you write something like a paragraph with the rules? Then I will be happy to upvote - and might not be the only one. Feel free to include sampe input and rules which have not been covered by @nfn neil good answer. (I did not downvote, just to be clear about this.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following regex will perform as requested:

```
^((.)(?!\2)(.)(?!\2)(?!\3).)\1$
```

https://regex101.com/r/eHKzWB/3

Comment: I need this to work for words with repeated letters that are not in sequence or at least also for words that are not in sequence. @nfn neil

Comment: I think I may have updated it since you last commented.  Go ahead and refresh.

Comment: Ok, I refreshed and it is still not quite what I am looking for. So, for example, that method is allowing for the word "booboo" to return as true. Where as "booboo" only has two different letters in it. I need for only words with 3 or more different letters, such as "pompom" to only return as true, and only if three of the letters are repeated (at minimum) but being specific to 3 letters would be ok also. This is my mistake I need to be more specific in my post, will update!

Comment: Yeah, I'm just debating on how to do it.

Comment: I'm gonna work on trying to use the hat to exclude *identical characters that are right next to each other... not exactly what i need but it would work for now

Comment: Just updated my response. Thanks for the question it was very interesting.  If you could mark as solution, it'd be much appreciated (click the green check mark).

Comment: Hey man! That will definitely do temporarily! Solid answer thanks I appreciate the help.... Wonder why someone down voted my question... I thought I was pretty thorough... anyhow... definitely will mark solution for ya.

Comment: You can replace the .'s with [a-z] if need be.

Comment: Your answer is wonderful. The .'s are fine. I was just wondering how you could make it to where there is no limit on how long the word can be. For example, crecrecre will not work. However for what I am using it for I only need it to work on 6 letter words at the moment.... Just always curious lol

Comment: Yeah, I don't know how to do that.